# SVG: Circle inside a polygon: Hide overflow

Tags: html, css, svg

I have created a simple figure using svg. 
Im trying to create a circle within a polygon.

**Question:** Is it possible to create a figure inside a polygon? 
The result I'm looking for is that any overflow from the circle is hidden.

As you can see in the below image, the circle breaks the boundaries of the polygon and the overflow is not hidden.

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="services-component-container" class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" style="padding: 0;">
    <svg id="ny-trakt-container" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
      <polygon class="state-1" points="0,20 48.5,15 48.5,45 0,31" style="fill:#ceffc9;" />
      <polygon class="state-1" points="0,33 0,80 48.5,85 48.5,47" style="fill:#ceffc9;" />
      <circle id="ripple-shape" cx="10" cy="20" r="5" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reuse the polygons as a clip-path to stop the circle from overflowing the polygon shape.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div id="services-component-container" class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" style="padding: 0;">
    <svg id="ny-trakt-container" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip">
          <polygon points="0,20 48.5,15 48.5,45 0,31" />
          <polygon points="0,33 0,80 48.5,85 48.5,47" />
      </clipPath>
      </defs>
      <polygon class="state-1" points="0,20 48.5,15 48.5,45 0,31" style="fill:#ceffc9;" />
      <polygon class="state-1" points="0,33 0,80 48.5,85 48.5,47" style="fill:#ceffc9;" />
      <circle id="ripple-shape" cx="10" cy="20" r="5" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```